# Geofence not triggering for my react-native implementation

Tags: android, react-native, broadcastreceiver, geofencing

Not sure if this is related to me trying to use it in a react-native module, it is more ore less the same - unless initialising it inside *ReactContextBaseJavaModule* is a issue.

Everything seems to work. Fence region is added to API without errors, but never triggering.

Maybe there is some trivial thing I have missed, but have gone over multiple tutorials and docs.

Code:

```java
public class BackgroundFence extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;
  private String TAG = "FENCE:BackgroundFence";

  BackgroundFence(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = false)
  public void createFence(double latitude, double longitude,int radius) {
    Log.d("BackgroundFence", "Create fence for " + latitude +":"+longitude+" r:"+radius);
    Activity activity = this.getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
    Context context = activity.getBaseContext();
    geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context);
    Geofence geofence = createGeofence(
      latitude,
      longitude,
      radius,
      Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT
    );
    GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
      .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
      .addGeofence(geofence)
      .build();

    List<Geofence> fences = geofencingRequest.getGeofences();
    Log.d(TAG,"Fences: "+fences.size());
    for (Geofence fence : fences) {
      Log.d(TAG,"Fence: "+fence.getRequestId());
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getGeofencePendingIntent();
    if (activity == null || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      Log.d(TAG,"No activity or permission");
      return;
    }
    geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
      .addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Geofence Added...");
        }
      })
      .addOnFailureListener(activity, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
        }
      });

  }

  private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    ReactApplicationContext context = this.getReactApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE );
  }

  public Geofence createGeofence(double latitude, double longitude, float radius, int transitionTypes) {
    return new Geofence.Builder()
      .setRequestId(generateRequestId())
      .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, radius)
      .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
      .setTransitionTypes(transitionTypes)
      .build();
  }

  private String generateRequestId() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "BackgroundFence";
  }
}
```

Manifest:

```xml
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

      <receiver
        android:name=".GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        />
```

Reciever:

```java
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private String TAG = "FENCE:GeofenceBroadcastReceiver";
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive!");

    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if(geofencingEvent==null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: geofencingEvent is null");
      return;
    }
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Error receiving geofence event...");
      return;
    }

    int transition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ENTER");
    } else if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: EXIT");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Not sure if this is related to...` ,? What is 'this'?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone running in similar issue. Geofencing events don't trigger in emulator. Spent a whole day till I figured this out.